# Как из массива выбрать неповторяющиеся элементы

Tags: c#

Есть массив Buttons, из которого необходимо выбрать Mins чисел и занести это все в массив fakeButtons
P.S Желательно не через LINQ

```
Random rand = new Random();
int Mins = rand.Next(2, 6);
int[] Buttons = new int[9] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } ;
int[] fakebuttons = new int [Mins];
```

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как это реализовать? Была мысль создать цикл с ограничением до Mins и в нем через if каким-то образом добавлять неповторяющиеся элементы в fakebuttons, но моих знаний сделать это не хватило

Comment: а чем linq-то плох?

Comment: @tCode Ну если других вариантов нет, то пусть будет LINQ

Comment: о каких "неповторяющихся" элементах идет речь?

Comment: @tCode Ладно, распишу полностью, чтоб вопросов больше не возникало. Мне необходимо в массив fakebuttons добавить допупстим 4 числа из массива Buttons, при этом , чтобы массив заполнился полностью и числа в fakebuttons не повторялись

Comment: После того как берете любое число из Buttons, удаляйте его там, чтобы не взять в следующий раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за советы! Решил проблему таки через коллекции. Код:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int Mins = rand.Next(5, 6);
List<int> lis = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
List<int> FakeButtons = new List<int> { };
for (int i = 0; i < Mins; i++)
{
    var b = lis[new Random().Next(1, lis.Count)];
    if (!FakeButtons.Contains(b)) { FakeButtons.Add(b); }
    else { i--; }
}
```

Comment: если использовать List<int> не нужно будет делать Convert.ToInt32

Comment: решение работает, только если в lis все элементы уникальны, если есть повторяющиеся, то может получиться, что в FakeButtons будут дырки

Comment: в принципе тут проверка `if (lis.Contains(b))` вообще лишняя, так как всегда true возвращает, потому что сначала ты "берешь" элемент из списка, а потому проверяешь - есть ли в списке этот элемент

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, исправил ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ну если правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int Mins = rand.Next(2, 6);
int[] Buttons = new int[9] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] fakebuttons = Buttons.Distinct().Take(Mins).ToArray();
```